How do I upload and fetch PDF files from MongoDB
I'm posting the file as formdata but when I fetch the data, I receive a blob that returns corrupted PDF file. My goal is to store the file in Mongodb as binary data and display it in browser.
Axios POST in React frontend
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        if (configuration) {
            axios(configuration)
                .then(async (res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                    const id = res.data.result._id;
                    try {
                        const formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('filename', licenseNo)
                        formData.append('file', file);
                        const res = await axios.post(`url/file/${id}`, formData, {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                            }
                        });
                        console.log(res.data);
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                    navigate('/');
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error.message);
                });
        }
    }

PDF Model
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const pdfSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    refId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    data: {
        type: Buffer,
        required: true,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('PDF', pdfSchema);

PDF POST Route
router.post('/:id', upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
    const filePath = req.file.path;
    const pdfName = req.body.filename + '_' + req.file.originalname;
    const pdfData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const newPDF = new PDF({
        refId: req.params.id,
        name: pdfName,
        data: pdfData,
    });
    newPDF.save()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'PDF uploaded successfully!',
                pdf: result
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        });
});

PDF GET Route
router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    PDF.find({ refId: req.params.id })
        .then((pdf) => {
            res.set({
                'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
            }).json(pdf)
        })
        .catch((error) => res.status(400).res('Error: ' + error))
})

Axios GET in React frontend
axios.get(`url/file/${id}`, {
                responseType: 'blob'
            })
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    setPdfData(URL.createObjectURL(res.data));
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));

The code mentioned above returns the following blob and cannot be rendered as a PDF
Blob console log
The PDF is being displayed using iframe tag
PDF viewer

The document size in MongoDB is limited to 16MiByte. Is that sufficient for all your PDFs?

@WernfriedDomscheit a single pdf in my case is approximately 1-2mb in size. 16mb would be sufficient for a document.
